# How to import pdf.js using cdn

Tags: javascript, cdn, pdf.js

I wanted to use pdf.js for a project of mine but I faced an issue of importing it, basically, the CDN doesn't work

Here is my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.7.570/build/pdf.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="my-canvas"></canvas>
<script>
    pdfjsLib.getDocument('./ahmed.pdf').then(doc => {
        console.log("this file has" + doc._pdfInfo.numPages);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and that is the errors that my console shows

> Deprecated API usage: No "GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc" specified.

> Uncaught TypeError: pdfjsLib.getDocument(...).then is not a function

So what should i do to solve this problem and thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

You have to set `GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc` to `/build/pdf.worker(.min).js` of same version:

```
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =
  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.7.570/build/pdf.worker.min.js";  

pdfjsLib.getDocument('./ahmed.pdf').promise.then(doc => {
  console.log(`This document has ${doc._pdfInfo.numPages} pages.");
});
```

**And**, as @Pasi has mentioned, you have to promisify `.getDocument()` by chaining `.promise` on it. Without it, there is no `.then()`.

Answer (score 1):

See the "Hello World with document load error handling" example on this page to get started: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/

(Your snippet is missing `.promise` after `getDocument()` and setting the `workerSrc` property)