# Change the entry of the pdf file to pass the exact path to it by me

Tags: javascript

I found this code which, you select a pdf file in an input, and it returns the number of pages it has. It turns out that with this way of reading pdfs is the only one I have found that reads absolutely all pdfs correctly.

What I am trying to do is to isolate the code that reads the pdf file, so that I can pass it the path to the file instead of using the input. It is to then read all the files in a folder and display the total number of pages.

But I can't figure out where exactly I would have to pass the path to the pdf file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>PDF.js Example to Count Number of Pages inside PDF Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center">Count Pages inside PDF Document</h1>
    <div class="form-group container">
        <input type="file" accept=".pdf" required id="files" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <h1 class="text-primary container" id="result"></h1>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.12.313/pdf.min.js"></script>
<script>
 
let inputElement = document.getElementById('files')
 
   inputElement.onchange = function(event) {
 
    var file = event.target.files[0];
 
    //Step 2: Read the file using file reader
    var fileReader = new FileReader();  
 
    fileReader.onload = function() {
 
        //Step 4:turn array buffer into typed array
        var typedarray = new Uint8Array(this.result);
 
        //Step 5:pdfjs should be able to read this
        const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(typedarray);
        loadingTask.promise.then(pdf => {
 
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "The number of Pages inside pdf document is " + pdf.numPages
            // The document is loaded here...
        });
                    
 
    };
    //Step 3:Read the file as ArrayBuffer
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: The browser will not provide file path information to a script.  So the only way you can get page count from the pdf is by using a file or blob object as in the example code. Yet, you might want to look at the [The File System Access API](https://web.dev/file-system-access/) for ideas.

Comment: @Yogi And there is no way to adapt the example I have given to be able to select more than one file in the input ?

Comment: Yes, you could allow the input to select multiple pdf files and and loop through the array of file objects.

Comment: @Yogi you leave me a little bit the same, I've never done that before. Forgive my ignorance

Comment: I posted the changes you need to make.  I think it is enough to get you started.

Comment: I added 2 more minor changes which should help you. See the "update" section. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 2 modifications to make it work.  Add "multiple" attribute to the input to allow the user to select multiple pdf files.

```
  <input type="file" multiple accept=".pdf" required id="files" class="form-control">
```

And then loop through the array of files to calculated the number of pages in each:

```
[].forEach.call(event.target.files, file => {
```

**Update:**
Two additional changes have been added.

**1.** We must reset the file input at the end of the loop. Otherwise it will only work once and then stop.

```
// clear file selector to allow reuse
event.target.value = "";
```

**2.** We also must set the value "workerSrc" to prevent a console warning message. More details about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66974404/how-to-import-pdf-js-using-cdn).

```
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.7.570/pdf.worker.min.js';
```

Run the code snippet to see how it works (hold shift key down to select multiple pdf files):

```js
let inputElement = document.getElementById('files')

inputElement.onchange = function(event) {

  [].forEach.call(event.target.files, file => {

    //var file = event.target.files[i];

    //Step 2: Read the file using file reader
    var fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = function() {

      //Step 4:turn array buffer into typed array
      var typedarray = new Uint8Array(this.result);

      //Step 5:pdfjs should be able to read this
      const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(typedarray);
      loadingTask.promise.then(pdf => {

        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += "<li>" + file.name + " has " + pdf.numPages + "pages</li>";
        // The document is loaded here...
      });


    };
    //Step 3:Read the file as ArrayBuffer
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

  })

  // clear file selector to allow reuse
  event.target.value = "";  

}

// Must set worker to avoid error: Deprecated API usage: No "GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc" specified.

pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.7.570/pdf.worker.min.js';
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h4 class="text-center">Count Pages inside PDF Document</h4>
  <div class="form-group container">
    <input type="file" multiple accept=".pdf" required id="files" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <ol class="text-primary container" id="result"></ol>
</div>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.7.570/pdf.min.js" integrity="sha512-g4FwCPWM/fZB1Eie86ZwKjOP+yBIxSBM/b2gQAiSVqCgkyvZ0XxYPDEcN2qqaKKEvK6a05+IPL1raO96RrhYDQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: @KJ - Thanks.  The console warnings were in the original example code too, but that is also fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Browsers don't let you access local paths on a user's computer for security reasons.

The browser doesn't get to know that the pdf is at `/home/USERNAME/confidentialdocs/file.pdf`, it just gets a data blob with a given filename.

Comment: There is no way I can use that pdf.js to tell you what to read and count your pages ? Even if I have to read the files one by one with a loop.